# Fill an array with sql query

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, pivot-table

Is there anyway to fill an multidimensional array with a sql query? My sql query results on a pivot table. As you can see, I want so make some sums (for Total Column and Total Row) and I want to know the best way to make that sums and percentages in that table.. I said multidimensional array because it could be easier. The code below works but I want to know how can I choose the rows and columns to make the sums. I'm using ASP.NET C#

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=****;Initial Catalog=***;User=sa;password=***");

        //query for all specialities
        string specstring = "SELECT Speciality.Shortname, SUM(1) as contar " +
                            "FROM DoctorEnterpriseDetails INNER JOIN " +
                            "Speciality ON DoctorEnterpriseDetails.Speciality1 = Speciality.SpecialityId INNER JOIN " +
                            " GroupType ON DoctorEnterpriseDetails.GroupId = GroupType.GroupId " +
                            " WHERE (DoctorEnterpriseDetails.EnterpriseId = 48) " +
                            " GROUP BY Speciality.Shortname ";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(specstring, conn);
        command.Connection.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        myDataAdapter.SelectCommand = command;

        // Adds rows in the DataSet
        //DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();

        DataTable specstringtable = new DataTable();

        myDataAdapter.Fill(specstringtable);
        specstring = ""; 
        for (int i = 0; i < specstringtable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            if (specstring == "")
            {

                specstring = "[" + specstringtable.Rows[i][0] + "]".ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                specstring = specstring + ", " + "[" + specstringtable.Rows[i][0] + "]";

            }

        }

        //GroupGrid.DataSource = cobtable;
        //GroupGrid.DataBind();
        command.Connection.Close();

        ////query for pivot table
        string querystring = "SELECT Description AS Categoria, " + specstring +
                             "FROM (SELECT GroupType.Description, Speciality.Shortname, SUM(1) AS contar, GroupType.GroupId " +
                             "FROM DoctorEnterpriseDetails INNER JOIN " +
                             "Speciality ON DoctorEnterpriseDetails.Speciality1 = Speciality.SpecialityId INNER JOIN " +
                             "GroupType ON DoctorEnterpriseDetails.GroupId = GroupType.GroupId " +
                             "WHERE (DoctorEnterpriseDetails.EnterpriseId = 48) " +
                             "GROUP BY GroupType.Description, Speciality.Shortname, DoctorEnterpriseDetails.GroupId, GroupType.GroupId) as ps " +
                             "PIVOT (SUM(contar) FOR Shortname IN (" + specstring + ")) pvt " +
                             "ORDER BY GroupId; ";

        ////Response.Write(querystring);
        SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(querystring, conn);
        command2.Connection.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter();
        myDataAdapter2.SelectCommand = command2;

        // Adds rows in the DataSet
        //DataSet myDataSet2 = new DataSet();

        DataTable cobtable = new DataTable();

        myDataAdapter2.Fill(cobtable);

        DataColumn cl = cobtable.Columns.Add("Total");
        cobtable.Columns["Total"].SetOrdinal(1);

        DataRow dr;
        dr = cobtable.NewRow();
        dr["Categoria"] = "Total";
        cobtable.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
        dr = cobtable.NewRow();
        dr["Categoria"] = "";
        cobtable.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 1);
        dr = cobtable.NewRow();
        dr["Categoria"] = "%";
        cobtable.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 3);
        dr = cobtable.NewRow();
        dr["Categoria"] = "";
        cobtable.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 4);
        dr = cobtable.NewRow();
        dr["Categoria"] = "%";
        cobtable.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 6);
        dr = cobtable.NewRow();
        dr["Categoria"] = "";
        cobtable.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 7);
        dr = cobtable.NewRow();
        dr["Categoria"] = "%";
        cobtable.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 9);

        GroupGrid.DataSource = cobtable;
        GroupGrid.DataBind();


    }
```

[image]c

Comment: I tried to use sql datareader so far, I can do it filling a datable with table adapter and bind it to a gridview.. it works... But after that how can I choose index rows to make the sums? @AndyKorneyev

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as a start. Then update your question with relevant code and add more details about what are you trying to do and what went wrong. It will help others to clearly understand your question and give an appropriate answer.

Comment: Ok, now i see a lot of code. ;) But I still can't understand - what is your exact problem. You are filling some datatable from database, then you're iterating over rows of datatable - so why don't calculate all sums you need in this iteration? Am I missing something?

Comment: Someone said to me that would be easier with a multidimensional array, that's why I asked @AndyKorneyev

Comment: Well, I don't think that using of multidimensional array instead of datatable can somehow simplify your task. It rather can make your code less readadble without any significant benefits. And the concept remains the same: you're still need to iteratу over rows and columnd and calculate your sums - it doesn't matter will it be dataRows or walking inside array with index calculations.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Can you give a sample to sum a entire row? e.g , I want to sum all fields (the grey fields) in "Medical" row and put it in the "Total" which is in the same row( value = 200) @AndyKorneyev

Comment: Assuming `dro` is `DataRow` of your DataTable and this table has all mentioned fields - it is just `dro["Total"] = Convert.ToDecimal(dro["END"]) + Convert.ToDecimal(dro["FIS"]) + .....`